# Open CTI Callback issue in Managed package

Tags: visualforce, opencti, callback

I am facing this issue that my Open CTI method callbacks are not executing in an org where I have installed managed package. They work absolutely fine on the org where I developed my application as well as if I upload my package as unmanaged. So, the problem I am facing occurs only when managed package is installed on an org.

Sample code:

```
var enableClickToDialcallback = function(response) 
{
 if (response.success) 
 {
    console.log('API method call executed successfully! returnValue:', response.returnValue);
 } 
 else 
 {
    console.log( 'Click to dial unsuccessful ' + response.errors);
 } 
};

function enableClickToDial() 
{
      sforce.opencti.enableClickToDial({callback: enableClickToDialcallback});
}
```

Other Open Cti methods are also not executing callbacks so it is not related to enableClickToDial only.

Please suggest a solution,
Thanks.

Comment: After you package the CTI app and install it in another org, are you able to see the "Open CTI Softphone" in the utility bar to test the VF page?

Comment: I am not packaging app, rather code only. After installing package, I create app and include "Open CTI Softphone" in utility bar.